# 503 Error ObjectifyService NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am having issues with GAE in the api explorer.I am trying to use objectify to save to a datastore but I am getting this error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Project.service.OfyService",
"code": 503,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "backendError",
"message": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Project.service.OfyService"
}
]
}
}
```

I tried to google it a bunch but came up empty handed. I am really new to GAE and somewhat new to Java. Here is what shows up in intelliJ's console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Project.service.OfyService
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestrict  ed(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at Project.saveProfile(ProjectApi.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Jan 25, 2015 12:39:14 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: Could not initialize class Project.service.OfyService
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Project.service.OfyService
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at Project.saveProfile(ProjectApi.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Here is my OfyService:

```
public class OfyService {
/**
 * This static block ensure the entity registration.
 */
static {
    factory().register(Game.class);
    factory().register(Platform.class);
    factory().register(Profile.class);
}

/**
 * Use this static method for getting the Objectify service object in order to make sure the
 * above static block is executed before using Objectify.
 * @return Objectify service object.
 */
public static Objectify ofy() {
    return ObjectifyService.ofy();
}

/**
 * Use this static method for getting the Objectify service factory.
 * @return ObjectifyFactory.
 */
public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
    return ObjectifyService.factory();
}
}
```

And my api:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public Profile saveProfile(final User user, ProfileForm profileForm)
        throws UnauthorizedException {
    if(user == null)
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization Required.");
    }

    String mainEmail = user.getEmail();
    String userId = user.getUserId();
    String displayName = profileForm.getDisplayName();
    Profile profile = new Profile(userId, displayName, mainEmail);
    ofy().save().entity(profile).now();
    return profile;
}
```

GAE SDK Version: 1.9.17

Objectify Version: 5.1.4

I have tried multiple different version combinations to see if it was the SDK's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NoClassDefFound` is thrown if the class cannot be found, or if it cannot be loaded. So, if static initialisation fails, you will get this error. In your case, the class failing to load is your own `ObjectifyService`, so its likely that `factory().register(...)` is throwing an exception.

To help diagnose the issue, you can wrap all the registrations in your static init block in a try/catch, log the exception/stacktrace then rethrow. The stack trace will help identify which of Profile, Game and Platform are causing the exception.

There is also no reason to wrap ObjectifyService like this, if you're using dependency injection you could just register classes at startup using your standard DI pattern, that way any exceptions will flow out of your startup as normal.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. Word to the wise though, stepping through this in debug mode takes forever as there is a TON of stuff going on.  What my main problem was is I didn't have @Entity on those classes I was trying to register. I planned on going through that later and setting that all up, I was just trying to get one of the classes working. Also, I don't under stand what you mean in your last paragraph, I will have to google it and see if I can figure that part out. I ended up moving the `register` to each of the classes per another article I read on here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its a bit hard to explain in a comment, but if there is anywhere else you can register classes that isn't a static init block, you should do that. Using spring, for example, you could do that when creating repository or service classes. See here for more info: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that documentation last night and it really shed some light on what I was doing wrong. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to declare `@Entity` for persisted objects
and `@Id` for their unique identifiers

```
@Entity
public class Profile {
    @Id
    Long userId;
    String displayName;
    String mainEmail;
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to put this into an answer because I also just spent a few hours having the same problem + solution as the OP and it wasn't till later that I bothered to read the comments =P

Putting this here so it is clearer for people to see:

The issue was I did not have `@Entity` on all of my entities that I was registering!